# Using playbooks in a sub-directory made group_vars unfoundable

Tags: ansible

Here is my Ansible project's files organization :

```
my-project
|__ group_vars
|   |__ my_group
|       |__ vars.yml
|__ inventories
|   |__ production.yml
|__ playbooks
    |__ subdir1
        |__ my-playbook.yml
```

The playbook `my-playbook.yml` refers to a group variable `my_var`. When I play the playbook from the project root directory with the command `ansible-playbook -i inventories/production.yml playbooks/subdir1/my-playbookyml` I get the following error :

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was:
> 'my_var' is undefined. 'my_var' is undefined

If i move the playbook to project root directory and run `ansible-playbook -i inventories/production.yml my-playbookyml` it's working well !

Am I missing anything in order to store my playbooks in a tree-structure ?

Comment: Only the inventory and playbook directories 
 are searched for *group_vars*. See [precedence 4.-7.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence)

Comment: Thank you for your hint, I've posted my solution according to what I've understood from the precedence doc !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Vladimir Botka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6482561/vladimir-botka) hint, I've resolved my case by moving the `groups_vars` directory to `playbooks/subdir1` :

```
my-project
|__ inventories
|   |__ production.yml
|__ playbooks
    |__ subdir1
        |__ group_vars
        |   |__ my_group
        |       |__ vars.yml
        |__ my-playbook.yml
```

Comment: Surely you want to put your `group_vars` in `inventories/` not `playbooks/` ?

Comment: I'm keeping `group_vars` in the playbooks section : I'm not used to IaS, and I'm a developer, not an Ops, so I probably have a weird approach. I use 1 project for a pool of machines, that have different functions (web/app server, db, mq broker), so each playbook uses its own variables and do not systematically concern every machines. To me it makes sense but maybe there are some disadvantages ?

Comment: I put defaults in playbooks/roles. So.. webserver ports 80/443 or postgresql on port 5432. Then in the inventory I put any non-default stuff (machine names, non-standard ports etc). My playbooks only target groups which means I do sometimes have a lot of groups with just one machine. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable